# Pandas - default masks values when indexing conditionally

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function which provides the index of the rows which satisfy some given condition (or a series of conditions).

```py
def some_function(df, a, b, c, d):
  return df.index[df["A"].eq(a) & df["B"].eq(b) & df["C"].eq(c) & df.eq(d)]
```

Now I want to ignore specific conditions if a value is not present.

```py
df.index[df["A"].eq(a) & df["B"].eq(b) & df["C"].eq(c) & (df["D"] if D == None else df["D"].eq(d)]
```

However, the above condition always returns an empty list.
It seems as the lack of a condition evaluation in `df["D"]` interferes with the final result.

Is it possible to conditionally evaluate a condition using `Pandas` (without writing two separate queries)? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Writing the expression with `df.query()` might give more flexibility.

Comment: @sj95126 I think that would work with some `f-strings` magic. Still wish there was a direct way to do it. Thanks for the suggestion :) +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the first part of the mask in a variable, and then update the mask using simple `if` statements:

```py
def some_function(df, a, b, c, d):
  mask = df["A"].eq(a) & df["B"].eq(b) & df["C"].eq(c)
  if d != None:
    mask &= df["D"].eq(d)
  return df.index[mask]
```

You also might be use your original attempt, only instead of `df["D"] if ...` use `True if ...`:

```
def some_function(df, a, b, c, d):
  return df.index[df["A"].eq(a) & df["B"].eq(b) & df["C"].eq(c) & (True if d == None else df["D"].eq(d))]
  #                                                                ^^^^ Replaced df["D"] with True
```